# Get latest package version with gulp

Tags: npm, gulp

I'm trying to write a gulp task which will run the npm command `npm view [package_name] version`.
After it I need to get the outcome of the command and do some changes on the numbers.

I tried with 'gulp-exec' and 'gulp-run' packages. Both of them are running the command which is printing the latest package version to the console but it's not accessible in the callback.

Wanted to ask how run the npm command and write the outcome of it into variable with gulp? Is there a way to run the state of the console so I can parse the last line?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use Node's child_process module:

```js
// Gulp 4, but will be almost same in Gulp 3
const {series} = require('gulp');
const {exec} = require('child_process');

const version = (cb) => {
    exec('npm view gulp version', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
        const npmOutput = stdout.trim();
        console.log(npmOutput);
        cb();
    });
};

exports.default = series(
    version
);
```